# fread и fwrite C

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! У меня есть две структуры:

```
struct Student
{
    char Name[20];
    char Surname[20];
    int Age;
    char Phone[20];
    char Address[20];
};
struct ArrayStudents
{
    Student **PtrSt;
    int Size;
    int Count;
    int Block;
};
```

Как можно записать структуру в файл используя только функцию fwrite(), чтобы была возможность позже загрузить эти данные через fread().

Comment: Во-первых, определитесь с заголовком и метками. Пока что ваш вопрос к C++ не имеет никакого отношения. Во-вторых, уточните что именно вам непонятно. Как работает `fwrite()`? Смотрите в описании вашей библиотеки, или `man fwrite`. Как записать с помощью `fread()`? Это просто: никак, `fread()` ничего не записывает в принципе.

Comment: Получается что главная структура ArrayStudents записывается в файл, но в ней есть вторая структура Student которая не записывается. И поэтому когда загружаю через fread данные, то вместо данных второй структуры мусор.

Comment: А вы действительно считаете, что здесь - сообщество телепатов, и все уже знают как именно и что вы делаете? (если намёк не понят - код покажите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если потелепатировать, то можно решить, что вы пишете в файл структуру ArrayStudents и ожидаете, что это повлечёт за собой автоматическую запись данных, на которые указывает поле PtrSt. Но это не так. Попробуйте посмотреть на созданную структуру в отладчике (режим дампа памяти), нарисовать на бумажке (руками! ручкой, карандашом...) распределение памяти при инициализации такой структуры и добавлении в неё студентов. Станет понятно, что 1) студентов записывать нужно отдельно и 2) всю структуру ArrayStudents записывать совсем не обязательно.

Например, запись:

```
struct ArrayStudents students;
/* ... добавили студентов ... */
fwrite( &students.Count, sizeof(students.Count), 1, file );
for( int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++ )
{
    fwrite( students.PtrSt[i], sizeof(struct Student), 1, file );
}
```

Чтение:

```
int Count;
fread( &Count, sizeof(Count), 1, file );
/* ... создали структуру ArrayStudents на Count студентов ... */
for( int i = 0; i < Count; i++ )
{
    fread( students.PtrSt[i], sizeof(struct Student), 1, file );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сохранение в файл работает, но вот в загрузкой проблемы. На этой строчке выбивает ошибку fread(a.PtrSt[i], sizeof(Student), 1, f1);
void LoadContacts(ArrayStudents &a)
{
 system("cls");
 FILE * f1 = nullptr;
 char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.txt";
 fopen_s(&f1, filename, "rb");
 if (f1 == NULL)
 {
  perror("Error: ");
  return;
 }
 a.Count = _filelength(_fileno(f1)) / sizeof(Student);
 fread(&a.Count, sizeof(a.Count), 1, f1);
 for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
 {
  fread(a.PtrSt[i], sizeof(Student), 1, f1);
 }
 fclose(f1);
 RussianMessage("Файл загружен!\n");
 _getch();
}

Comment: Ну так прочитайте сообщение об ошибке, что пишут? Кроме того, в логике опять проблема (зачем вы читаете a.Count, если определяете сколько там записей по длине файла?)